# multiple sheet lookup in excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I am trying to write a VBA code to do lookup in excel.

What I have is two worksheets and want to lookup between these two sheets and lookup result should be present in third sheet. How will be able to do this in VBA.

SHEET1:

```
CHANGE NUMBER  |DATE    |
---------------|--------|
1555081        |5/3/2018|
1555083        |5/3/2018|
1555089        |5/3/2018|
1555327        |5/3/2018|
1555381        |5/3/2018|
1555526        |5/3/2018|
```

**SHEET2:**

```
TICKET NO     |CLIENT REFERENCE ID|
--------------|-------------------|
T20161103.0040|1555081            |
T20170113.0057|1555526            |
T20170113.0064|1555589            |
T20170125.0035|1555083            |
T20170130.0091|1555526            | 
T20170130.0092|                   | 
T20170208.0073|                   |
```

My lookup formula will be

```
= vlookup(sheet1!A1,sheet2!B:B,1,FALSE)
```

How can I do that in VBA. Any help will be appreciated

Thanks
Abdulquadir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for a start

> My lookup formula will be
>
> = vlookup(sheet1!A1,sheet2!B:B,1,FALSE)

.

```
Sub randomstackmacro()
Dim output As String
Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet

'This will apply the vba on cell C2 // Please modify this according to your requirements>
Range("C2").Select



Set Sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set Sheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
output = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheet1.Range("A3"), Sheet2.Range("A:B"), 2, False)

 'Output of Vlook up is set to the active cell as an example
ActiveCell.Formula = output

End Sub
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: I ran the code. It does not give me any error but I dont get any output as well. Just to comfirm there are 3 sheets - sheet1 ,sheet2 and output is on sheet3. And I am creating this VBA code on sheet3.

Comment: i think I need to update the last line to Sheet2.Range

Comment: Try the updated code now, Also from your formula I understand your workbook sheets are sheet1 and sheet2 right ?

Comment: I dont see any change in code. But i did try it and still same. No result

Comment: Okay, I have recreated the module on PC, and have update with screenshot example.
Hope it is clear

Comment: This works now. But this does just for the row specified. How do I do it for all the values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170389/discussion-between-clint-and-abdulquadir-shaikh).

Comment: This solutions work, but in my case it gives incorrect result. But can be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub lookuptest() 

Worksheets("CA").Range("A:A").Copy Worksheets("OUTPUT").Range("A:A") 


On Error Resume Next 
Dim cn_Row As Long 
Dim cn_Clm As Long 
Dim sheet1 As Worksheet 
Dim sheet2 As Worksheet 
Dim sheet3 As Worksheet 

Set sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CA") 
Set sheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AT") 
Set sheet3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OUTPUT") 

With sheet1 
sourcelastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 
'MsgBox "source file last row is: " & sourcelastrow 
End With 

Table1 = sheet1.Range("$A$2:$A$" & sourcelastrow) ' Employee_ID Column from Employee table 
Table2 = sheet2.Range("B:B") ' Range of Employee Table 1 
cn_Row = sheet3.Range("B2").Row ' Change E3 with the cell from where you need to start populating the Department 
cn_Clm = sheet3.Range("B2").Column 

For Each cl In Table1 
sheet3.Cells(cn_Row, cn_Clm) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, Table2, 1, False) 
cn_Row = cn_Row + 1 
Next cl 
'MsgBox "Done Lookup with Change Number" 

Dim id_row As Long 
Dim id_clm As Long 

Table3 = sheet1.Range("A:B") 
id_row = sheet3.Range("C2").Row 
id_clm = sheet3.Range("C2").Column 

For Each cl In Table1 
sheet3.Cells(id_row, id_clm) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, Table3, 2, False) 
id_row = id_row + 1 
Next cl 

MsgBox "Done" 

End Sub
```